# UIAlertView fades in from top right how to stop

Tags: ios7, uialertview, subview

I have added a scrollview as a subview and it drops down in to my view when a button is clicked but when I click the logout button the UIAlertView behaviour has changed since I added it in. When I click on logout the UIAlertView fades in from the top right. Don't see why the behaviour has changed or why it would do that any ideas?

```
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize showMenu;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Members Area";

showMenu = false;

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

}

- (IBAction)LogOut:(id)sender{
UIAlertView *logoutMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout"
message:@"Are you sure you want to logout?"
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[logoutMessage show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([title isEqualToString:@"No"])
{
    //NSLog(@"You clicked No");
}
else if([title isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
{
    //NSLog(@"You clicked Yes");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LogoutView" sender:self];

}
}

- (IBAction)DropDownMenuMembers:(id)sender{


if (showMenu == false) {

    showMenu = true;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
   // openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(267,101, 47, 30);

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
else{

    showMenu = false;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
    [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 100);
    //openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(262, 20, 47, 30);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem with the animation, this resolved the issue:

[How to slide UIView from side on top of current view (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784891/how-to-slide-uiview-from-side-on-top-of-current-view-iphone)